# How can I increase my supply voltage with more batteries?

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging

I am currently using this circuit to power something but it turns out I need more voltage than the 3.7 that my battery currently supplies. Is there a safe way to incorporate another battery into this so I can get higher voltages? I have more tp4056 if that is something that could help.
[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need more voltage? You *could* replace the MCP1700 with a DC-DC buck/boost converter. But consider @JRE's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

No because that charger is meant for 1S batteries. It cannot support multiple batteries in series. You need a charger circuit for 2 Series batteries. And then your higher voltage causes issues with your chosen regulator MCP17000. 2 fully charged lithium ion batteries in series are up to 8.4 Volts. You will need to change that regulator. Some esp32 boards have linear regulators so you may be able to skip that part. Google the regulator part for its datasheet.

Yes because you could add in a boost convertor. This would work on the existing setup, taking the lithium battery voltage and boosting it to 7V like you need. But the draw back is the power needs will drain your battery quicker AND the efficiency penalty (10 to 20%) will do so as well. You could add a parallel battery (get two fresh ones) for increased capacity, as that charger can support that.

Answer (score 2):

An ESP32 is perfectly happy with 3.3V or less.  Many modules have a 3.3V pin.  Just connect the 3.3V  output of the MCP1700 regulator to the 3.3V pin of your ESP32 module.

The MCP1700 should still output voltage even when the cell voltage drops below 3.3V.  The output will be lower than 3.3V, but the ESP32 can run on anything from 2.2V to 3.6V.

---

Using two of your lithium cells would be a bad idea.  The input voltage limit for your MCP1700 is 6V.  The sum of two of your lithium cells would be over 7V - the regulator would probably die if connected to two fully charged lithium cells in series.

Comment: I suppose I should have specified I am powering an esp32 but I am hopping to drive a motor which needs ~7 volts off of this as well.

Comment: Then you need a 2S charger and a regulator that accepts at least 8.5V and can do 3.3V output at the current the esp needs. Also edit your question to add that info. It's important.